# Question about libmatio-dev

Tags: apt, development

I want to install `libmatio-dev`, but a specific version (1.3.4-2). Whenever I run `sudo apt-get install libmatio-dev`, I get 1.5.2 installed instead. How do I force the install of 1.3.4-2?

Comment: apt-get install libmatio-dev 1.3.4-2 try and make sure whether it helps!

Comment: E: Unable to locate package 1.3.4-2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '1.3.4-2'I tried it before,but thanks for help!